# Scanner or InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, java-io, inputstreamreader

What advantages does `InputStreamReader` have over `Scanner` class?

Scanner seems better to me in all aspects.

Why do I have to use `throws IOException` with `InputStreamReader`?

For example:-

1)

```
BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

2)

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
```

What is something that 1) can do and 2) cannot?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: Khalid Shah I came across that answer but mine is basic level and I didn't get what I was looking for over there.

Answer (score 0):

When using Buffered reader we need to import java.io package so we need to handle exception either by try and catch or by using throws Exception. There is one disadvantage of using Scanner class when we use nextLine after nextInt: 
 it does not read values and the output is different from the expected output

//example scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class c 

{

    public static void main(String args[]) 

    {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Enter an integer"); 

        int a = scn.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Enter a String"); 

        String b = scn.nextLine(); 

        System.out.printf("You have entered:- "+ a + " " + "and name as " + b);

    } 


}
```

Input: `2,rajat`

Expected output: `You have entered:-2 and name as rajat`

Actual output: `You have entered:-2 and name as`

It does not take rajat in string b whereas there is no such problem with BufferReader class

//example Buffered Reader

```
import java.io.*; 

class c

{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 

    { 

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new

        InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        System.out.println("Enter an integer"); 

        int a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 

        System.out.println("Enter a String"); 

        String b = br.readLine(); 

        System.out.printf("You have entered:- " + a + " and name as " + b); 

    }

}
```

Input `2,rajat`

Expected output: `You have entered:-2 and name as rajat`

Actual output: `You have entered:-2 and name as rajat`

Comment: Why is this error happening with `Scanner`?

Comment: I guess it is because the line is broken or already used because of integer? I added an `scn.nextLine()` and now it works normally.

Comment: Ok I have figure out the problem. Are there any other differences?

Comment: You're comparing Apples or Oranges @AdityaSoni. `InputStreamReader` just reads `char` from an `InputStream`. `Scanner` tokenizese - if you're writing an XML parser for example, you don't need tokenization, you just need the data. The answer I have linked goes into some detail about all the different methods and what they can be used for. As a general rule, `Scanner` is vastly slower because of the tokenization it does so should be avoided if you don't need it.